# Reseting a 128 adress* 16 words memory

Tags: verilog, memory

I'm doing my term project, in which I have a memory, which can be changed by the user. The specification is that whenever reset is activated, data on this register should be reset to all zeros.

I first declared the memory consisting of 128 addresses* 16 words as follows

```
    reg [15:0] memory [127:0];
```

Here is the code that I try to use for resetting purpose

```
    always @(posedge clk)
    begin
    if (reset)
   begin
    for (i=0; i<256; i = i+1) 
        begin
            memory[i] <= 16'b0000000000000000;
        end
   end
```

This is my attempt to solution. I tried synchronus reset approach.

Now the crucial thing that I want to ask is, can I use for loop inside always ? I have made some research and I found that for loop is not synthesizable for the FPGAs, which are required during the demonstration of projects. Without using for loop, how can I make the 16 bits in all 128 addresses all zero? It seems impossible to me ? I am quite new to Verilog so it may be a noob question.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please explain why you want to reset this memory in the first place. In many cases, a reset is not necessary.

Comment: It's explicitly asked as a design requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The loop is perfectly synthesisable, except for the fact you are counting to 256 when you only have 128 addresses.

However what you are going to infer is not a memory, but rather 2048 discreet registers. If that's what you want, then you should have no problems, but it probably isn't. Memory blocks in FPGAs don't have array reset signals (they have reset signals for the address and output registers, but not the data array). If you want to reset the contents of a memory block you can't do it in one go.

You have two options if you want to infer a memory rather than registers.

The first option would be to have a counter and over the course of 128 clock cycles set each address in turn to zero. That takes a long time.

The second option would be to have 128bit wide register (one of each memory word). You use that register to indicate whether or not the memory word is valid. To reset the memory you clear the 128bit register to indicate none are valid. You can then use the valid bit to determine whether to output the value in the memory or zero. The advantage of this approach is you can clear the data in a single clock cycle by clearing the valid bits.

Comment: I corrected the i inside for loop to be <128.

Comment: if the loop is sythesizable as you said, then I can use it. The problem is that during the labs, assistants told us not to use for or while loops inside always. They told us that during for loop operation, a clock pulse may come and enter always again, while the before for loop is finished and it made sense to me. I actually investigated in the truth of this and made a dummy code 
reg [3:0] out[3:0];

always @(posedge clk)
begin
for (i=0; i<4; i = i+1) 
out[i]<=4'b0000;
and it worked quite well. In conclusion, will using for loop inside the always cause a problem in real life or no?

Comment: You can think about the for loop in this situation as a shortcut to save you a lot of typing; it will be "unrolled" during synthesis and nothing will actually iterate in the implemented logic.

Comment: @DenizYildirim in which case your assistant is incompetent and needs to go back and learn Verilog and HDL design. This is not computer programming, it is hardware description - everything in an always block can be thought of to "happen at the same time" (oversimplification, but a good start). The synthesizer follows the loop at compile time and unrolls it (turns each pass of the loop into physical hardware). `while` loops and for loops with indeterminate length will probably error out when you try to synthesize them as the compiler doesn't know how much hardware to add.